# How can i import the seedSuperpixel modules?

Tags: import, module, superpixels

I wanted to implement the SEEDS Superpixel segmentation algorithm in python using opencv but it looks like other than video module no other module has been put up in order to implement it. Please help me know what module needs to be used to import the seeds superpixel segmentation functionalities?

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem to use SEEDS.

At least for my problem, I had to install "opencv-contrib-python" and uninstall "opencv-python" because both are imported the same way (using "import cv2") but only the contrib version allows you to use SEEDS and other segmentation tools. There is more information here https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/

I don't know if that will work for others, but solved my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

To use SEEDS for Superpixel segmentation analysis, you need to import cv2.

I found this [bit of code](http://ddokkddokk.tistory.com/18) and was able to replicate results after [installing opencv](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/opencv).

Comment: Hi modriano thanks for the code..it gave me an idea about the ximgproc module which can be utilized after installing the opencv-contrib version to use the non-standard opencv packages